# Problem about triggering View's $(document).ready handler on Controller response in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc

We are trying to change our HttpServlet to Spring's DispatcherServlet. We use jQuery and JSP in client side. And there is some dynamic stuff in our pages.

For ex there is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        window.alert("alerted!");
});
```

in a `blah.jsp`. And we are triggering it by calling

```
$("#myDiv").load("blah.jsp");
```

from another `.jsp`

Then I made configurations about Spring MVC. And observe new controllers are totally working.

Here is the problem. Controller returns "blah" View from servlet, it is a html string. And i can't make it's `$(document).ready` handler trigger when i append it to `$("#myDiv")`.

How can i figure this out?

C.O.

Comment: ... could you post a bit more of the js code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess is that the problem is that the script is not being run after the you insert the response payload into the page.

so, i think if you specify a dataType attribute in the ajax call, the scripts should be run once inserted into the document

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "blah.jsp",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#myDiv').html(data);  
      },
      dataType: "html"
    });
```

or

```
    $.get("blah.jsp", null, function(data) {
        $('#myDiv').html(data);  
      }, "html");
```